# I have multiple buttons on a page, which user can select from. How to get that selection data in JSON format?

Tags: javascript, html, json, alpine.js

I making a quiz where the options are html buttons. How do I get the data on what buttons the user selected before pressing next into JSON format? There are more pages of questions from which data should be dynamically be added to the JSON until the final submit button is clicked.
Thanks in advance!

Here's the working code pen: https://codepen.io/sikapoor/pen/ZEQajzx

````
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="assets/img/favicons/crafty_favicon.svg">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.2/dist/tailwind.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,400i,600,600i,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-168037965-1"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-168037965-1');
  </script>
</head>
<body class=" font-custom min-h-screen">


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.3.5/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>


    <div class = "flex flex-wrap justify-around pt-10">

      <div class = "p-5">
        <div class="p-5" x-data="{ active: false }">
          <button :class="{ 'bg-green-200': active }" class="hover:bg-green-200 border border-gray-700 py-2 px-4 rounded w-40 text-left text-black font-bold" @click="active = !active">
            Option1
          </div>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class = "p-5">
        <div class="p-5" x-data="{ active: false }">
          <button :class="{ 'bg-green-200': active }" class="hover:bg-green-200 border border-gray-700 py-2 px-4 rounded w-40 text-left text-black font-bold" @click="active = !active">
            Option2
          </div>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class = "p-5">
        <div class="p-5" x-data="{ active: false }">
          <button :class="{ 'bg-green-200': active }" class="hover:bg-green-200 border border-gray-700 py-2 px-4 rounded w-40 text-left text-black font-bold" @click="active = !active">
            Option3
          </div>
        </button>
      </div>
      
        <div class = "p-5">
          <div class="p-5" x-data="{ active: false }">
            <button :class="{ 'bg-green-200': active }" class="hover:bg-green-200 border border-gray-700 py-2 px-4 rounded w-40 text-left text-black font-bold" @click="active = !active">
                Option4
            </div>
            </button>
        </div>
  
    <div class = "p-5">
      <div class="p-5" x-data="{ active: false }">
        <button :class="{ 'bg-green-200': active }" class="hover:bg-green-200 border border-gray-700 py-2 px-4 rounded w-40 text-left text-black font-bold" @click="active = !active">
            Option5
          </div>
        </button>
    </div>

    </div>


    <div class = "text-center pt-10">
        <a href="page3.html" class = "px-20 py-5 bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yellow-600 border-black rounded text-black font-bold w-48">
          Next
        </a>
      </div>
    
      

    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: When posting to StackOverflow, your code should be the minimal reproducible example. Please don't include things like your Google tags and fonts

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a new `x-data` for each button, you should have one `x-data` for the whole form. Your buttons will update `x-data` on click

```html
<div class="flex ..." x-data="{question_1_active: false, question_2_active: false}">
  <button :class="{ 'bg-green-200': question_1_active }">
```

Your submit button then has access to all of the fields. You could jsonify the fields and submit them to the server.

```html
<button x-on:click="fetch('/your_endpoint', {
  method: 'POST,
  body: JSON.stringify({
    'question_1_active': question_1_active,
    'question_2_active': question_2_active,
  }

})">
```

You could also consider using a select tag or check boxes which will let you use `x-model` instead of watching each click for changes.